# Compute each limit or state that it does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to compute the limit or state it doesn't exist for: **$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{\frac{1}{3}} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{x}\big]\big]}$**

I have already computed that: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{x}\big]\big]}$ does not exist. Since if we let $x_n = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and $y_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n}$ we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n = 0$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{x_n}\big]\big]} \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{y_n}\big]\big]}$.

How would I now compute the limit above?

Comment: Take its absolute value and use the very definition of limit

Comment: As the question is worded, you can just state that it doesn't exist.  It doesn't seem to ask that the statement be true, just that you take one of two actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that as $x \to 0,  (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor}$ is either $-1 $ or $1$, ie both finite values. But as $x\to 0,  x^{1/3} \to 0$.

So the overall limit must be $0$ (product of finite value and a number tending to zero).

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$0\leq \left| x^{\frac{1}{3}} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{x}\big]\big]}\right|\leq x^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

thus by sqeeze theorem

$$x^{\frac{1}{3}} (-1)^{\big[\big[\frac{1}{x}\big]\big]}\to 0$$